# Looking for an API that can provide the amount of flights bought from point a to point b on daily basis

Tags: datasets

I would like to know if any of you could help me finding an API source to gather information on daily bookings/sales from point A to point B, i.e. how many seats were sold landing or finishing a trip in Dallas airport and where was the beginning of the trip (point of departure).

I will truly appreciate any help, data does not need to be real time, a day or two, even a week delay would be fine. I am trying to correlate demand with other multiple variables but need to get the data from the demand side.

Thanks in advance for your comments

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure you can get the data easily.
IATA developed the NDC standard an API for airlines, which might enable you to check flight bookings between two destinations.
Nonetheless, as with any industry wide standard, it is interpreted in many different ways by the companies implementing it. Hence a pain to develop.

The most simple solution would be to use a set of well defined APIs from an airline ticketing company. [Amadeus](https://developers.amadeus.com/) is one of them and I am almost sure they provide these kind of information.

In both cases, you are looking at quite a high upfront cost (in the thousands).

Comment: Thank you for the help! I already tried Amadeus and they replied with a negative answer. I will try IATA!

Comment: Let me know if you don't find anything, I might know someone who has the answer.